# Spyder Python Animation not working

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, spyder

I'm working on a python project using spyder from anaconda and I am trying to get the animation function working.

I found a basic animation example here: http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/examples/animation/basic_example.html
and tried to make it work.

However when I run it, nothing happens both in the Python and iPython console.

I found this answer: [Animation from matplotlib not working in spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856079/animation-from-matplotlib-not-working-in-spyder) However, changing the preferences does not do anything and typing in %matplotlib qt returns: No module named qt4.

Spyder Version: 3.1.0
Running on MacOS Sierra

Comment: Did you try running it using the option "Execute in a new dedicated python console" from the "Run Settings"? Can you run a normal matplotlib example without animation? Can you run the example from the normal system console outside spyder? How did you install matplotlib and spyder?

Comment: I just tried those settings now, but still I am getting nothing. Yes, normal matplotlib works without the animation. I have tried running the example outside spyder in idle, but I don't have the relevant modules. I did not specifically install matplotlib and spyder, but I downloaded anaconda navigator and launched spyder which had matplotlib preinstalled.

Comment: If you do not have the relevant modules, you cannot run it (if idle cannot find the modules, spyder will not find them either). So I suggest installing "the relevant modules" (whatever you mean by that).

Comment: I mean that I can run a basic matplotlib in spyder without having to install the modules, however in python it says no module named matplotlib

Comment: Do you have by now two python versions installed? The one from anaconda and another one? That can cause huge problems.

Comment: Yes I do, it is very confusing. What would you recommend doing?

Comment: The best way would be to uninstall both of them, make sure they are completely off your computer. Then install exactly one python distribution, either anaconda or any other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the answers. I found out my error, it was that I forgot to add .py to the file name so Spyder did not recognise them as python files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run

```
%matplotlib qt5
```

before running the animation, instead of

```
%matplotlib qt
```

because that only works for Qt4.